# Do manufacturer phone updates typically overwrite the bootloader?

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

I have a phone that was rooted for me by one of the cleverest guys I know. Sadly, I've since lost all contact with him. I've decided to try to port cyanogenmod to this phone, however I'm completely on my own here: no tools, no recovery image, no nothing. All I have is the official LG updater, and my phone in its ideal rooted state.

So then, here is my question. I want to be able to fall back on something when I inevitably screw up this phone in my quest to port CM to it. Should I expect the LG updater to replace the awesomely rooted bootloader my friend put on for me? If so, then I would lose the ability to play with this phone.

Comment: Exactly what phone do you have? Also, this more of a question for http://android.stackexchange.com/ than Stack Overflow. You'll have more luck asking over there.

Comment: I have an LG SU 950, which is a Korea-only model, meaning I'm completely on my own here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to answer my own question here: Yes.

I performed an update with the hopes of grabbing an updated system image, and bam! Unlocked bootloader is gone.